# Search query in Sumologic - Contains

Tags: sumologic

I'm a bit lost with a search query in Sumologic. I need to get logs where `_sourceHost` contains `production`

In case of SQL it looked like this

```
WHERE app="my-app" AND _sourceHost LIKE "%production%"
```

Does somebody knows if it's possible in Sumologic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this:

```
| where _sourceHost matches "*production*"
```

see also:

https://help.sumologic.com/Search/Search_Query_Language/Search_Operators/matches

https://help.sumologic.com/Search/Search_Query_Language/Search_Operators/where

Answer (score 2):

You can add wildcards to your string for `_sourcehost=` I don't know if app= is a part of your string or if it's an indexed value. If it's just part of the log string, it would look like this:

`"app=\"my-app\"" AND _sourceHost=*production*`

Otherwise it might be

`app=my-app AND _sourceHost=*production*`

One step further, you can use the wildcards in the middle of strings too, e.g.,

`prod*box` would match `prod553box` or `prod999box` or `prodfoobox`

Answer (score 1):

you can use regex to match the wording.

```
(_sourceCategory="dev/test-app")
| parse regex field=_raw "(?<pre> \w*)production(?<suff> \w*)"
```

[sumologic query screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EtuY.png)